# Can't delete a folder on WIndows 11 because apparently it doesn't exist

Tags: windows-11, files-folders

I was making an npm package in a folder "guessthegame" and after some time I've noticed I also have a sibling folder "guessthegame." which mirrors any change I make to the original folder: new file, delete file, update file etc.

If I try to delete the mirrored folder it deletes the original folder instead and then the mirror folder still shows up in file explorer yet I can't open/delete it and just get the error that this directory is not available.
I've tried rebooting my PC in safe mode and deleting the folder again - didn't help. I've tried force removing with powershell & cmd - either they say there is no such directory or it just silently finishes but the folder is still there.
In addition tried all of the above with the parent folder and get similar errors.

Running a dir command show that there is an empty folder with no name in the directory - screenshot below.
Also if I create a sibling folder "guessthegame" again then the mirror folder will become available again and will continue to mirror any changes to the original folder.

Screenshot of powershell dir command and file explorer:

[image: Screenshot of powershell dir command and file explorer]

Comment: Have you tried deleting it using the 'rd' command? Try 'rd /q /s "C:\Users\ckuka\VS Code Projects\Chrome Extensions\guessthegame.\"'

Comment: I suggest to run `chkdsk`.

Comment: Shut down, start up and try deleting again. If no and no to the above suggestions, try Unlocker 1.92 (Major Geeks). Windows Defender complains about Unlocker so whitelist it.  I use this and on Windows 11.

Comment: @John, defender rightfully complains since Unlocker 1.9.2 installs a search hijacking thing. Isn't there enough free unblocking tools without this unwanted behavior?

Comment: @YisroelTech running 'rd /q /s "C:\Users\ckuka\VS Code Projects\Chrome Extensions\"' in cmd in admin mode( not PowerShell for whatever reason) surprisingly helpled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested by @YisroelTech I've run cmd in admin mode with
`rd /q /s "C:\Users\ckuka\VS Code Projects\Chrome Extensions\"`
command and it finally deleted the directory.